# Доступ к методу абстрактного класса общего для нескольких классов

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bean

У меня есть три класса, являющиеся компонентами.

```
@Component
class One extends SuperClass{};
@Component
class Two extends SuperClass{};
@Component
class Three extends SuperClass{};
```

SuperClass - это абстрактный класс, который имплементирует интерфейс, содержащий metodInterfase(); который переопределяется в каждом из основных классов со своей логикой. В самом же SuperClass этот метод metodInterfase(); никак не реализуется т.к. он и не нужен.

В супер классе так же есть public void() который используется в каждом из основных классов.

У меня возникает проблема как получить доступ к public void() у SuperClass из основных классов?

Если я просто создаю переменную в основных классах типа

```
@Component
    class One extends SuperClass{
    private SuperClass superclass = new SuperClass(); // ошибка
    @Override
    public void metodInterfase(){};
};
```

ИДЕ просит меня реализовать метод metodInterfase() для SuperClass что для меня бессмысленно.

а если попытаться сделать SuperClass компонентом и заинжектить его то получаю сообщение от ИДЕ Could not autowire. There is more than one bean of 'SuperClass' type. что логично поскольку я использую этот класс у нескольких других.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> как получить доступ к public void() у SuperClass из основных классов

*Этот метод, наверное, как-то называется?*

Его надо просто вызывать:

```
methodFromSuperClass();
```

Comment: точно он же public! ужс =)